# wxPython unexpected indent

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

Starting on wxPython and getting an unexpected indent error.

```
  File "gui_texteditor_men.py", line 18
helpMenu= wx.Menu()
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I've checked my code, (im using notepad++) and all the indents are fine, not sure where I've gone wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx
import os

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        self.dirname=""

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size =(200,-1))   
        self.CreateStatusBar() 


        fileMenu= wx.Menu()
        helpMenu= wx.Menu()
        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open"," Open a file to edit")
        menuAbout= filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.

        #HELP MENU
        menuAbout = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About", "About this program")  

        #add events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)


        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.buttons = []
            for i in range(0, 6):
                self.buttons.append(wx.Button(self, -1, "Button &"+str(i)))
                self.sizer2.Add(self.buttons[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # Use some sizers to see layout options
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.control, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        #Layout sizers
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Show()

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A small text editor", "My test editor", wx.OK)  #create a dialog (dlg) box to display the message, and ok button
        dlg.ShowModal()  #show the dialog box, modal means cannot do anything on the program until clicks ok or cancel
        dlg.Destroy()  #destroy the dialog box when its not needed

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)  #on menu item select, close the app frame.

    def OnOpen(self,e):
        self.dirname=""  #set directory name to blank
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file to open", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN) 
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:  #if positive button selected....
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename() 
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()  
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r') 
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())  #open the file from location as read
            f.close
        dlg.Destroy()

app = wx.App(False)   #creates a new app
frame = MainWindow(None, "Simple Text Editor")  #give the frame a title
app.MainLoop()  #start the apps mainloop which handles app events
```

Checked the syntax and didn't spot anything obvious, is anyone able to?

Comment: think the formatting messed up when I put into SO. thats all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that.

To fix your file, run Python in mixed tabs-and-spaces error mode:

```
python -tt yourscript.py
```

then configure your editor to use *only* spaces for indentation, and replace any tabs with spaces. Using only spaces for identation is recommended by the [Python styleguide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: ran it as you suggested and got error:
  File "gui_texteditor_men.py", line 12
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(600,400))
                                                               ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @BenMarks: There you go. Replace tabs with spaces in your editor, correct any inconsistent indentation you now have and configure your editor to *only* ever use spaces.

Comment: yup, just done that and replaced all the tab with spaces, works again. thanks